# Replace or remove everything after the first few lines

Tags: notepad++

I've got a lot of long XML files and I want to replace everything in them after the 4th line, I've been looking around and can't find anything with the expressions to select everything after the 4th line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CMapData>
<name>garage_door_locked</name>
<parent />
select everything from here to the end of the file
```

Is such a thing possible with regular expressions? Also, the first 4 lines are entirely different in each of my files. I just need to skip them somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\A(?:.*\R){4}\K[\s\S]+\z`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\A          # beginning of file
    (?:         # non capture group
        .*          # 0 or more any character but newline
        \R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
    ){4}        # end group, must appear 4 times
    \K          # forget all we have seen until this position
    [\s\S]+     # 1 or more any character
\z          # end of file
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    (?:.*?\R){4}
Replace: (empty)
```

The above logic will match the first 4 lines.  We then replace with nothing to effectively remove them.  Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/J1nPjz/1).